# npm publish with git information instead of version from package.json

Tags: git, npm, continuous-integration, npm-publish

I am trying to find a solution to publish a npm artefact based on the git information.

I looked to [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) and [release-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/release-it), but these tools automate git actions (commit/push) to make the link between npm artefact version and git, it doesnot get the information from git.

I would like to publish npm artefact with git identification of its source, something like the result of `git describe --tags --always`.
Like this it could be possible to make the link between git/npm easily and the only git action is tagging, the continous integration pipeline could publish the artefact through `npm publish`.

[git-tag-version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-tag-version) seems making a part of the job, but doesnot makes the link with artefact version.

I will probably try to go in this way, but maybe there is some features in npm that allow to do this more easily ?

Answer (score 6):

`npm version from-git` seems not far from what I liked to do, except :

- it needs a annotated tag
- it commits the updated package.json
- it doesnot have a different identification still the lastest tags stay the same

So finally I was using:

```
npm config set git-tag-version=false 
npm version $(git describe --tags)
npm publish
```

This doesnot commit the package json modification and allow to works with lightweight tag